# How many maxima and minima an n-degree polynomial can have at most?

Tags: calculus

There's a statement: "Given a polynomial of degree 6, it may have up to 6 real roots, corresponding to 3 minima and 3 maxima."

Is this true in general?

How to get the number of maxima and minima separately for an arbitary n-degree polynomial?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the number of maxima and minima separately"?

Comment: No its not. A quadratic polynomial has one extremal point (see parabola).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Are there any methods to determine the number of maxima and the number of minima solely by observing the degree of the polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For polynomials of degree $2$ or greater, it is not possible to know the number of (real) roots using only the degree of the polynomial.  In general, a polynomial of degree $n$ can have $n - 2k$ roots (for some integer $k$), where "repeated roots" are counted separately. That is, roots are counted "up to multiplicity."

For your example, a polynomial of degree $6$ can have either $6,4,2,$ or $0$ roots (up to multiplicity). For example, the polynomial
$$
f_1(x) = x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)
$$
has $6$ real roots, and the polynomial
$$
f_2(x) = x^6 + 1
$$
has $0$ real roots. The polynomial
$$
f_2(x) = x^2(x^4 + 1)
$$
has $2$ real roots, both of which are equal to $0$.

With that established, the maximal number of minima that a degree $n$ polynomial can have is $\lceil (n-1)/2) \rceil$. For $n=6$, we see that the maximal number of minima that such a polynomial can have is $\lceil (6-1)/2 \rceil = \lceil 2.5 \rceil = 3$.

The maximal number of maxima is the same.  However, note that the total number of extrema (minima and maxima) of a degree $n$ polynomial is at most $n-1$.

Comment: $f_1$ is a $7$ degree polynomial having $7$ real roots.

Comment: @Martund fixed, thanks.